# call external web service from WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, esb, jboss-esb, wso2-esb

I'm in an internel network and I want to create a service (ESB) to call an external get service.
for example my **ESB** service path: `uri/esb/path/param1/param2`
my **external** path: `external/path/param1/param2`

here my entry

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/services/KRI-getIndividualVehicleFuelco2" name="KRI-getIndividualVehicleFuelco2" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="renault_error_format" scope="default" type="STRING" value="json"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="getIndividualVehicleFuelco2" value="********** begin **********"/>
                <property expression="get-property('RequestID')" name="RequestID"/>
            </log>
            <Delegation.DelegationIn>
                <Jboss-Endpoint-Key>KRI-customAddressingTransformation.xml</Jboss-Endpoint-Key>
                <Custom-Sequence-Header>KRI-commonsequences-processSpecialHeadersIn</Custom-Sequence-Header>
            </Delegation.DelegationIn>
            <loopback/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <sequence key="KRI-commonsequences-genericErrorHandling"/>
            <Delegation.DelegationOut>
                <Jboss-Endpoint-Key>KRI-customAddressingTransformation.xml</Jboss-Endpoint-Key>
                <Custom-Sequence-Header>KRI-commonsequences-processSpecialHeadersOut</Custom-Sequence-Header>
            </Delegation.DelegationOut>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="getIndividualVehicleFuelco2" value="********** end **********"/>
                <property expression="get-property('RequestID')" name="RequestID"/>
            </log>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <loopback/>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

I created an endpoint with the base uri of the external service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="KIS-fuelco-PPD" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address uri="http://kisre701.intra.com/kis/api/v2/individual-vehicle-fuelco2/"/>
</endpoint>
```

how can I parse parameters and send them to endpoint?